# Возможно ли добавить одному GameObject несколько тегов?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Могу я добавить одному и тому же объекту 2 или 3 тега, типа Player и другие?

Comment: нет, зачем ,,,,,?

Comment: А могу ли я добавить к одному объекту несколько BoxCollider и добавить как-то к ним теги, чтобы полнимать, что, например, у игрока верхняя часть, где нижняя, где конечности?

Comment: можно составить игрока из нескольких GameObject каждый со своим коллайдером и тегом

Comment: Хорошо, допустим, игроку выстрелили в руку. Произошел OnCollisionEnter руки и пули. Как от руки передать информацию главному скрипту, весящему на главной части игрока - с помощью дополнительного скрипта?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавить несколько нельзя. Но есть такие варианты:

---

#### Проблема

К примеру мне нужно сортировать воинов в своём игре по тегам

> - `Ближний бой` - `CloseFighter`
> - `Дальний бой` - `DistantFighter`

> - `Новичок` - `Newbie`
> - `Опытный` - `Experienced`
> - `Легенда` - `Legend`

> - `Мужской` - `Male`
> - `Женский` - `Female`

Допустим есть некий герой который `Опытный`, `Женского пола` и владеет луком, то есть `Дальний бой`.

---

#### Решение 1

Соединим всё это в 1 строку, именно это строка будет у неё тег: `DistantFighter_Experienced_Female`.
Теперь вы можете спокойно взять её тег, разделить по символу `_` и сортировать.

---

#### Решение 2

Создать абсолютно новый скрипт (к примеру `Tags.cs`) для фильтрации. Пример:

- Tags.cs

```cs
public class Tags: MonoBehaviour
{
    public string[] TagsList;
}
```

- Скрипт фильтрации

```cs
[SerializedField] private GameObject[] _ObjectsToFilter; //Все объекты для фильтрации с скриптом Tags.cs

private void Start()
{
    foreach(GameObject _Object in _ObjectsToFilter) //Берём каждый объект
    {
        string[] _Tags = _Object.GetComponent<Tags>().TagsList; //Получаем список тегов каждого объекта
        foreach(string _Tag in _Tags) //Берём каждый тег
        {
            if(_Tag == "CloseFighter") //И проверяем
            {
                Debug.Log($"Боец {_Object.name} хорош в ближнем бою.");
            }
            else if(_Tag == "DistantFighter")
            {
                Debug.Log($"Боец {_Object.name} хорош в дальнем бою.");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log($"{_Object.name} бракованный боец. Несите нового.")
            }
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня была такая идея. Видимо ничего лучше нет. Но в таком случае мне придется создавать до фига тегов. Допустим добавим еще магическую атаку, потом добавим средний уровень прокачки между новичком и опытным и мастера между опытным и легендой, а еще добавим ребенка к Мужской/Женский как отдельный тип игрока. Тегов получается:  3*5*3=45 тегов только для ваших вариантов. Не слишком ли это... ну... тупо?

Comment: Кстати, скажите пожалуйста, как вы делаете эти полоски между дальний бой и новичок, легенда и мужской?

Comment: @МаксимФисман Если про `это`, то вот [так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFdOg.png). И кстати у меня идея получше появилась. Шяс дополню.

Comment: Нет, были полоски между группами про длину боя и опытность. Но теперь они пропали

Comment: @МаксимФисман это [горизонтальная линия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#horizontal-rules). Можно сделать с помощью <hr>, но я предпочитаю три тире: - - -

Comment: Три коротких тире?

Comment: @МаксимФисман Да, с пробелами между ними. `- - -`

Comment: @МаксимФисман ну а вообще вы всегда можете нажать `Править` под ответом и посмотреть какой элемент как написан.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, но вы можете создать новый тег, для себя